# How to handle this in ML mind?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a time series dataset, which contains the energy consumption of a product by each unit over time. It also contains the unit dimentions like model, years of usage, product version etc.

We want to find clusters of units which consistently shows higher consumption.

The dataset looks like this:

```
EventDate, UnitID, energyConsumptionRate, Model, YearsOwned, SoftwareVersion

5/1/2018      100            103             M3            1            2.1

5/2/2018      100             42             M3            1            2.1

5/3/2018      100             78             M3            1            2.1
....
```

One each day, the unit will report one event. Where should I start?

-Ch

Comment: So... what is this data that you've posted? Is it a plaintext file that needs parsing, a CSV file, a database, or something else?

Comment: Also, "ML" is a class of languages, like "Lisp" or "BASIC". It doesn't refer to a specific language, so I suggest adding a more specific tag: you're probably either thinking about SML or OCaml.

Comment: What do you mean by "higher consumption"?  Higher consumption compared to what... other units?  some other baseline?

Comment: ML here represent machine learning, sorry if I wasn't clear about it. The data reside in a SQL Database. For "higher consumption", yes we have a acceptable range of consumption values.

Comment: Your problem statement is a bit vague.

Comment: Have a look at BigML - it might be your easiest option (it clusters house prices easily, nice visualisation), or R might be a suitable language. It’d cluster easily enough. Alternatively convolving over time might work (maybe TensorFlow). But I suspect this is a "recommendation" question and could be considered off topic. I think there’s a machine learning variant of SE.

Comment: I think your question is too broad. Are you asking how to approach clustering? That might be more appropriate in Cross Validated or Data Science. Or are you asking what python command or package to use for clustering?

Comment: I tried to load the data into a data frame in Python with the goal to find cluster of units based on its consumption characteristics. Should I transform the consumption rate to categorical value to simply the dataset? like High consumption unit, medium, and low etc. Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: how many rows (entries) does this database have?

Comment: It's a pretty large table with 300M rows.

Answer (score 1):

Imho you can do this with supervised learning, no unsupervised learning (=clustering) needed.

1. Transform the feature `Event Date` to `number of days since start` by considering the earliest date for each unitID as the first day (at this day this feature would be 0).
2. Transform the features `Model` and `SoftwareVersion` to one-hot-coded, categorial features.
3. Normalize all numerical features so the values are floating point numbers in a range of [0, 1] or [-1, 1] or something in that value range.
4. Make a set of all unitIDs.
5. Remove 10% of that set and name it "validation set".
6. Remove another 10% of that set and name it "test set". Name the remaining 80% "training set".
7. Compute a model using the entries belonging to the `unitID`s in the training set. Use a neural network if you have at least 10-100k entries, or a gaussian process if you have less than that. The model takes the features `number of days since start`, `Model`, `YearsOwned` and `SoftwareVersion` as inputs and targets to predict `energyConsumptionRate`.
8. Do early stopping regarding the validation set (in case you use NNs).
9. Apply the resulting model on all entries belonging to the `unitID`s from the test set.
10. Do this 10-fold so every data point has been in the `test set` once and your table with the test-set-based model predictions from step `9` covers every `unitID`.
11. Make a query to find all `unitID`s where the actual `energyConsumptionRate` is considerably higher than what the models say.

You probably only need a very tiny model for that, with few free parameters. Maybe you can also achieve your goal with a sophisticated SQL query and basic statistics, not using machine learning at all.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it some thinking.